# How to configure Quartz.net database schema name?

Tags: c#, sql-server, app-config, quartz.net

I am unable to find a configuration entry to change the database schema name used by Quartz.net when the instance is persisted in SQL server. below is the portion of the configuration I am using to point it to SQL server Database.

```
    <quartz>
           <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="quartz" />
           <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="AUTO" />
           <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
           <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="4" />
           <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
           <!-- Database job store -->
           <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
            <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="false" />
           <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionStringName" value="DatabaseConnectionString" />
           <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
        </quartz>
```

I was expecting something similar to how it lets you configure the table name prefix. is there any configuration property I can use to change the schema name ... I want the the tables to be

qrtz.QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS

Instead of the default

dbo.QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS

I couldn't find any documentation on this, if it is at all possible. something like below for example ???

```
 <add key="quartz.jobStore.schemaName" value="qrtz" />
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A specific setting for schema does not exist.

You can try to "string hack it" with

```
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="[MySchema].QRTZ_" />
```

Comment: Works with java as well, Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reporting Ahmad.